# http proxy on my GWT server-side code

Tags: gwt

I have an REST server as backend, it provides a set of services, also, it uses  **basic authentication** method for access.

Now I need to create an GWT frontend,so, I need to perform http calls to the REST backend from the GWT frontend

After some research I found the HttpBuilder to handle http requests to the backend, but it seem to be a pain when trying to perform cross-site requests, and also it comes with some restricions related with Safari browser.

Then I found this https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite article, where it talks about an "Proxy on your own server", so it looks to be the solution I was looking for, but I did not find more information, or an example. It says that I could create **server-side** code to download the data from remote server (backend), so, should I create a **http client** like the apache client on **server-side** code, and implement a set of services that use it to make request to the backend?, if yes, how to handle the user authentication and the session? if not, give me a light please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   it seem to be a pain when trying to perform cross-site requests,
```

Actually you can make Cross Site Requests from GWT RequestBuilder if we can set in Servlet Response Header

Response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://yourrestserviceur.com/url");

```
should I create a http client like the apache client on server-side code, and implement 
a set of services that use it to make request to the backend?
```

No, it is not required. use `RequestBuilder`

**RequestBuilder Example:**

```java
     RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

        try {
          Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
              displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
              if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                updateTable(asArrayOfStockData(response.getText()));
              } else {
                displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText()
                    + ")");
              }
            }
          });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
          displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
    }
```

Comment: Please note that this header is part of CORS, and CORS isn't supported on all browsers, just relatively modern browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more details on this feature.