# CORS and GWT does it work now?

Tags: gwt, cors, gwt-rpc

I have been trying to get cross domain RPC calls to work on my GWT app because I would like to deploy my java script directly onto a users mobile device and then have it make RPC calls to the Google App Engine.

App currently works fine but only if the JS is downloaded on the fly to the client.  I see this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6502) on gwt from 2 yrs ago. Any know if it is still a problem or had any luck with **cross Domain RPC calls**?

Comment: +1 for query. You need to highlight the RPC aspect of your query :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, see here: http://css.dzone.com/articles/cross-site-requests-gwt

However this requires fairly modern browser so if you are after support also on older devices, than JSONP is safer bet (for that you can use JsonpRequestBuilder or RestyGWT).

**EDIT:** I just realised that you asked specifically about RPC. So this does not answers your question, but might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I only bumped into a work around suggested around 2010 in a [blog](http://experienceswithgwt.blogspot.in/2010/04/gwt-and-cross-site-requests_28.html). It is seriously hacky though.

Maybe we can try using some ideas from [http proxy on my GWT server-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363652/http-proxy-on-my-gwt-server-side-code)

GWT discussion on same topic - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/TFZsxQIeQXs/cQtKHVKCAr8J

**Note** - Based on Broyer's comment you might want to re-evaluate your requirements!!!

Comment: Thomas Broyer's comment there was to not try to use RPC serialization in native code - I'm not sure the same logic would apply with the same JS deployed to multiple servers or locally to devices.